# MSVC: Embedding Data in Program

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm hoping someone has run into this sort of problem before, and can give me a hint to solve it.

With Microsoft Visual C++ 2005, I have this code in a program:

```
DWORD locator[FOURXFLAGCOUNT+1]={
    0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858,
    0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858,
    0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858,
    0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858,
    0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858,
    0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858,
    0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858,
    0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x58585858, 0x00000000
};
```

The idea is to make the `locator` discoverable (and fillable) from *outside* the program -- i.e. another program is filling it in, so that this program will have it built in when it starts up. This is for an anti-theft thing, so there's no conventional way to get the data, it has to be done something like this.

This worked just fine when I was compiling the program on its own, but when I added a static library to the program, the data vanished. The `locator` symbol is still there; the data it's supposed to be initialized with (and which is supposed to be visible outside it) isn't.

The linker switch /OPT:NOREF solves the problem, but at an unacceptable price: the program grows by several hundred K (doesn't seem like much, but it is in this case). Using the `#pragma comment(linker, "/include:?locator@@BLAHBLAH")` (don't remember what the "BLAHBLAH" part was) did nothing -- the `locator` symbol is already visible, it's just not initialized. Moving the `locator` definition into the library doesn't help either.

Ditching the static library is a last resort, I'd rather not do it if I can avoid it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting thought, and thanks, but it didn't. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to find any acceptable solution to this problem. The linker is just too aggressive about what it trims... maybe a bug, maybe deliberate, though for the life of me, I can't imagine a case where you would *want* to eliminate the initialization of a variable while keeping the variable itself.

For now, I've turned on the /OPT:NOREF option. I'll just have to deal with the extra size, at least until I can find a way around it.

Comment: Check your assembly language manual.  Some assembly languages can *include* another file.  You could put the data into a file and have the assembly language *include* it in the data section.  This allows you to change the data in the file with a text editor which *may* be easier than changing the assembly language.

Comment: (For those who can't see how Thomas Matthews' comment relates, check the edits for the answer. It does, though only tangentially to the original problem.)

Comment: I have an issue in the same area so I visited, my optimized-out variable goes back into the source (along initialization) if I loop it and print the reduction. Now you claim the initialization gets optimized out, but thats if you dont print the values correct? Because if you print the value and the data does not have initialization it would print something diferent to what the code implies and thats a bug. If you can print the reduction then just reduce it all the way to whitespace and print that. I would expect it to initialize everytime, perhaps not where/how you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing DWORD locator to static DWORD locator.  Not sure if it would help but just a thought.  Alternatively, include a reference to locator somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Tried both already, to no avail. As I said, the symbol is there, it's just missing the data that it's supposed to be initialized with.

Comment: At a small function that iterates through the values, say to compute a checksum, to prove the data has been included.

Answer (score 0):

Add an function which uses `locator`, e.g. which builds the xor over it. You don't need to call this function, but you have to export it by adding it to the .DEF file or by using `__declspec( DllExport )`.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, that's not the problem -- `locator` is already there, it just isn't initialized like it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that the locator is being optimised out because nothing references it? Would putting something like this in your main program help?

```
DWORD d=0;
int i=0;
for (i=0; i<FOURXFLAGCOUNT; i++) d += locator[i];
```

Or even just this, but maybe not on all compilers:

```
(void)locator[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried something similar to your first suggestion before I asked the question. No luck. The linker wasn't optimizing away the `locator` symbol, just its initialization. The more I think about it, the more I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make a difference if you declare the array extern?

Comment: I had it declared `extern` in a number of modules, but it still has to be declared normally somewhere, and it's the normal declaration that's having trouble.